# how to programmatically (preferably bash) add icon to dmg?

Tags: bash, icons, macos-sierra, dmg

I have a bash script that creates a .dmg for my node.js app.  However, the icon for the .dmg that appears in Finder is the standard disk icon.  I need it to be the same icon as the app.

I know I can `cmd+I` on my .app in Finder, copy the icon, and `cmd+I` on my .dmg and paste.  But I want my build process to be fully automated.  I prefer not to use a third-party tool for this, since I already have code signing and localization working in my bash script.

I have tried copying my icns as `.VolumeIcon.icns` into the root of my dmg.  It has no effect.

I have also tried `SetFile -a C "path/to/dmg/.VolumeIcon.icns"`.  That doesn't have any effect either, and `man SetFile` says it is deprecated anyway.  I'm building on macOS Sierra 10.12.6.

Since a simple copy and paste works, there must be a way to do this programmatically!  But how???

**Update**

This partially works:

```
hdiutil create -srcfolder "my/build/dir" -fs HFS+ -fsargs "-c c=64,a=16,e=16" -format UDRW -volname MyAppName -ov -attach "my/output/dir/MyAppName.uncompressed.dmg"
SetFile -c icnC "/Volumes/MyAppName/.VolumeIcon.icns"
SetFile -a C "/Volumes/MyAppName"
```

It does not associate the icon with the .dmg file itself, but if I double-click the .dmg file, the Finder window that is displayed has my icon.

The primary need, though, is for the .dmg file itself.  When someone downloads my .dmg, I need the .dmg file sitting in the Downloads folder to have my icon instead of the standard disk icon.  As noted above, that's easy manually, but how can I do it from within a bash script or AppleScript?

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.owsiak.org/?p=683 - I am referring there to quite old, but still very good book. Unfortunately, it is available via SafariBooksOnline - paid service.

Comment: @mko I found instructions for the background image, but not for setting the icon displayed in Finder for the dmg file itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have image like this

[image]

and it's saved as: **cc.png**. Do following

```
cp cc.png cc_copy.png
sips -i cc_copy.png
DeRez -only icns cc_copy.png > icns.rsrc
mkdir some_installer
hdiutil create -volname installer -srcfolder ./some_installer -ov -format UDZO my_app.dmg
Rez -append icns.rsrc -o my_app.dmg
SetFile -a C my_app.dmg
```

and you will end up with:

[image]

Is that what you are looking for?

**Update:**

Should work for **icns** as well

```
cp /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/macOS.icns .
cp macOS.icns macOS_copy.icns
sips -i macOS_copy.icns
DeRez -only icns macOS_copy.icns > icns.rsrc
hdiutil create -volname installer -srcfolder ./some_installer -ov -format UDZO my_app.dmg
Rez -append icns.rsrc -o my_app.dmg
SetFile -a C my_app.dmg
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I think that's exactly what I'm looking for, but I'm actually starting with a .icns, not a .png.  Is there a way to to do this starting from a .icns, or do I need to first convert it to a .png?

Comment: Work great, thanks!  My only concern is the man page from Terminal on Sierra 10.12.6 says "Tools supporting Carbon development, including /usr/bin/SetFile, were deprecated with Xcode 6."  Same thing for DeRez and Rez.  Is there another way that is not deprecated?

Comment: To be honest I never used anything else, so, I don't know other ways of working with dmg files. In fact, I also use Rez to add license statement into dmg file: http://www.owsiak.org/?p=700

Comment: ok thanks.  Great post on adding a license to the dmg!  I guess when the deprecated commands stop working someone will find a new solution, and in the meantime I'm happy to have something that works now.

Comment: Any updates on this as the deprecated commands stopped working now.

Comment: ~Lothar - my solution is `Open Source` :) It means anyone is highly encouraged to update it as he/she likes :)

Answer (score 2):

You might be missing one step prior to your SetFile command.  Try this.

```
SetFile -c icnC "path/to/dmg/.VolumeIcon.icns"
SetFile -a C "path/to/dmg"
```

More information here: http://docplayer.net/20858155-How-to-create-a-yosemite-installer.html

Comment: Thanks - this gets the icon into the Finder window that opens when you double-click the installer.  Not what I was trying to ask, but helpful also.